# Recursive Fibonacci Function (With Negative Numbers)

Tags: c++, function, recursion, fibonacci

I am able to write a recursive Fibonacci function for all numbers greater than 0, but the function is completely incorrect for anything negative.  Any idea how to implement this in c++?

```
int fibonacci(int n){
    if(n == 0)return 0;
    if(n == 1)return 1;

    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

Comment: What is the definition for Finonacci of negatives?

Comment: Show us what you have?

Comment: Ok so it's not a c++ question? Is it an algorithm question?

Comment: I guess the definition is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Extension_to_negative_integers

Comment: Change the sequence order and isolate the *smallest* value rather than the largest. The general sequence is `F(n) = F(n-1)+F(n-2)`, Move the `F(n-1)` to the other side of that equivalence: `F(n-2) = F(n) - F(n-1)`

Comment: If you want to save a line of code you can, substituting the 2 ifs for only 1. I will let you know wonder how :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers, the recursive function for negative numbers is different than for possitive numbers.

For possitive:
    `n_2 = n_1 + n_0`

For negative:
     `n_-2 = n_-1 - n_0`

So that the recursivity works "just the other way around" and the same code will not work. You will have to write a new function.

EDIT: Wikipedia provides the generalization: F_-n = (-1)^n F_n so just compute F_n and modify the sign with (-1)^n

Comment: It has to work inside one function.  I was told it could be done recursively in 8 lines of code.

Comment: Then post the code you have and what is your problem exactly. Is this a C++ question or an algorithmic question?

Comment: Take a look at my edit. Probably that is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Your solution was perfect.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late on this thread however here is my 2 cents on the issue.

As shown on the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Negafibonacci) entry, Fibonacci can be bidirectional.
In order to implement it in [PHP](http://php.net/) you need to first check if the inbound parameter is negative so you know how to handle it later on as it does require a different formula to handle the negatives.

Take note that the negative side of Fibonacci numbers do not always yield a negative value.

The formula for bi-directional is:

F<sub>-n</sub> = (-1)<sup>*n*+1</sup> x F<sub>n</sub>;

Fibonacci requires seeding for 0 and 1 and when implementing the bi-directional Fibonacci you also need to account for <sub>-1</sub> as shown in the 2 exit points.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
F−6 | F−5 | F−4 | F−3 | F−2 | F−1 | F0 | F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 | F5 | F6
----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+------
−8  |  5  |  −3 |  2  | −1  |  1  |  0 |  1 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  5 | 8
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below is my variation of the Fibonacci to handle negatives;

```
function negaFibonacci($n) 
{   

    // seed+exit
    if(($n == 1) || ($n == -1))
    {
        return 1;
    }   
    // seed+exit
    if($n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }    

    if($n < 0)
    {
        //https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Negafibonacci
        return pow(-1,$n+1) * negaFibonacci(abs($n));
    } 
    else
    {
        //standard fib calc
        return negaFibonacci($n - 1) + negaFibonacci($n - 2);
    }


}
```

The function can be improved further with the rounding function but I have left it as is for readability.

Comment: Additionally, here is a link to the Fibonacci online calculator that takes **negative** numbers. https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573404

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it, I guess:

```
int fibonacci(int n){
    if (n < 0)
        return fibonacci(n * -1) * -1;
    if (n == 0) || (n == 1)
        return n;
    else
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```