# Fibonacci series using alternate approach is not working

Tags: recursion, tail-recursion

I have written a simple fibonacci series using recursion as below. But the below program is based on the formula `fib(n)=fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)`.

Can we write a program to take a value of n and compute the fibonacci series using the formula `fib(n+2)= fib(n)+fib(n+1)`. Can we write a program based on this formulae taking n as input.

```
 public class FibonacciClass{

  public static void main(String[] argv){

      for (int index=0; index < 7; index++){
          System.out.println("The Fibonacci series for the number "+index+" is " + fib(index));
      }

  }

  private static int fib(int n){
        if (n == 0 ) return 0;
        if (n <= 2 ) return 1;

      return (fib(n-1) + fib(n-2));
  }
}
```

If we can solve the fib series using recursion, please let me know your inputs to write the program for the same.

Answer (score 1):

hmm this sounds like you're trying to get an answer to a homework problem.  But looks like you have legitimate reputation so:

Define 
gib(n) = fib(n+2).
Use this to substitute for fib(n) and fib(n+1):

gib(n-2) = fib((n-2)+2) = fib(n)

gib(n-1) = fib((n-1)+2) = fib(n+1)

So the original equation becomes

fib(n+2)= fib(n)+fib(n+1)  --> gib(n) = gib(n-2) + gib(n-1)

And we can recurse on this.  We must make similar substitutions (n for n+2) in the code:

```
static unsigned int gib(int n)
{
  if (n <= -2) return 0;
  if (n == -1) return 1;
  return gib(n - 2) + gib(n - 1);
}
```

I didnt include negative numbers that result in negative fibonacci (your code breaks on them too) so truly it needs to be returning "unsigned int".  To modify for negative see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858498/recursive-fibonacci-function-with-negative-numbers).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your inputs. My question is a bit different. 

For example, if we want to iterate over an array, we can dot it in two ways.
 
First way is to start the index from 0 till the end of the list in a for loop.

Second way is to start from the end of the list and decrementing the index every time inside the for loop.

The program that I have posted is where the fib series is generated using previous two fib numbers. Can it be done in reverse way like we saw in the array example?

Comment: I don't see a way that this is possible because the definition of the fib series is that a result at a given index depends on results from prior indices.  Maybe there's some theoretical way of taking all the (infinite) results from positive infinity down to your number in order to determine the results from prior to your number. Perhaps you could try math.stackexchange.com     (disclaimer: I have never tried it myself) but it probably won't be code-able!