# Fibonacci sequence "nth term finder" doesnt seem to work when I input negative numbers

Tags: java

So what I am trying to do is ask the user for a number and find what its fibonacci term would be. So far, if an integer 0 <= is entered, then it returns the correct fibonacci term. But when I try to use negative numbers I get an error.

code:

```
 public int fib(int n) {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1 || n == -1) {
            // if n is 1, 0 or -1
            return Math.abs(n);
        } else if (n < 0) {
            // if n is negative
            return (-1)^(n + 1) * fib(n);
        } else {
            // if n is positive
            return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
        }
    }
```

errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Fibonacci.fib(Fibonacci.java:133)
    at Fibonacci.fib(Fibonacci.java:133)
    at Fibonacci.fib(Fibonacci.java:133)
    at Fibonacci.fib(Fibonacci.java:133)
    at Fibonacci.fib(Fibonacci.java:133)
    at Fibonacci.fib(Fibonacci.java:133)
    at Fibonacci.fib(Fibonacci.java:133)
    at Fibonacci.fib(Fibonacci.java:133)
    at Fibonacci.fib(Fibonacci.java:133)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things are wrong with your code. First of all, `^` is not exponentiation, but a bitwise xor. Instead, you have to use `Math.pow`. Also, you call `fib(n)`, when you should call `fib(-n)` (so that you get the fibonacci number for the positive index):

```java
return ((int) Math.pow(-1, n + 1)) * fib(-n);
```

Comment: Java has a unary minus operator.

Comment: This helped, thanks a lot but there was a problem with your answer. The code should be `return (int) (Math.pow(-1, n + 1) * fib(-n));`.

Comment: @Aplet123 Nice. I have never used unary operators even though I have been using Java for quite some time now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this to find an answer about implementing  the negative part of Fibonacci sequence (it's in c++ but it helps):
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858498/recursive-fibonacci-function-with-negative-numbers#:~:text=Take%20note%20that%20the%20negative,in%20the%202%20exit%20points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858498/recursive-fibonacci-function-with-negative-numbers#:%7E:text=Take%20note%20that%20the%20negative,in%20the%202%20exit%20points).